# Does the VerticalCallout algorithm in PieChart3D work correctly?

Tags: graphics3d, bugs, plotting

In real world usage you often want to use real world labels with long strings (say 15-20 characters) in 3D pie charts. Here is a toy example :

```
Clear[labeler];
labeler[datax_][v_, {1, c_}, ___] := 
  Placed[Column[{datax[[c]], v}, Alignment -> Center, 
    BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", 11]], 
   "VerticalCallout"];
data = Transpose[{"This is label " <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[14], 
    Range[14]}];

PieChart3D[{data[[All, 2]]},
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileSector3D", "Profile" -> 4],
 ChartStyle -> 54,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 LabelingFunction -> labeler[data[[All, 1]]],
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
 PlotRange -> All,
 SectorOrigin -> {Pi, 0},
 SectorSpacing -> 0.2]
```

[image]

We see that the plot area seems to have been determined without reference to the labels that will be placed around the chart. Consequently the labels are cut off.

Q. Is this an `Image Padding` issue?
A. no (note that `All` gives the same output as `Full`)

[image]

Q. So why not expand the margins around the image to give the labels enough space to be rendered?

[image]

So increasing the image margins merely creates another graphics area around the original image.

This looks like a bug or design flaw to me. Does anyone have any ideas about how to get `VerticalCallout` labels working in `PieChart3D`?

Comment: Setting `ImagePadding` to 100 works for me with your example. Also, [possible duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46549/does-the-verticalcallout-algorithm-in-piechart-work-correctly) ;-)

Comment: Not really a duplicate @rasher :) The other post is dealing with vertical alignments. This one deals with visible range. Still looks like a bug or design flaw because `ImagePadding->All` should adjust to include the labels. i.e. you should not have to set a value for each specific chart. Having said that, the manual value for `ImagePadding` does provide a work around.

Comment: Ah - just saw titles, figured it was double-submit... sorry. Glad manual setting at least provides work-around.

Comment: It seems like a ViewPoint issue. Try setting something like `ViewPoint -> 1.4 {0, -2.4, 2}`. (That vector is the default for `PieChart3D`.) Possible feature suggestion for WRI? "Make `Graphic3D` et al smart enough to scale `ViewPoint` to account for labels" or something to that effect?

Answer (score 3):

WRI Tech support confirm a bug. `ImagePadding->All` should work.

**Edit**

To address Bretts comment: In 2D `ImagePadding->All` works -- the `ImageSize` increases in the *x* direction by the amount of padding required. Nothing has to give. Why does something have to give in 3D?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use the string form of this comment as the label for a chart? It won't line-wrap by default, and the graphic has a fixed size, so something has to give...

Comment: @BrettChampion If it is intended, as opposed to a genuine bug, that something has to "give" then it seems pointless offering "VerticalCallout" and RadialCallout" as labelling options in 3D for real world usage. In 2D of course nothing "gives" and `ImagePadding->All` works as expected. ...but then the vertical alignments of labels issues exists http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46549/does-the-verticalcallout-algorithm-in-piechart-work-correctly

Comment: @BrettChampion I could stick labels in a `Pane` with fixed size, and have them wrap, and then set a fixed `ImagePadding` based on the `Pane` width but still not seeing why `ImagePadding->All` does not work.

Comment: Can you post your code for that 2D chart?  I'm not reproducing it.  According to the docs for `ImagePadding`, "Padding specified by `ImagePadding` is left **inside** the region defined by `ImageSize`" (emphasis mine) so your picture in not what I expect to happen.

Comment: @BrettChampion the code is the same as the link in my first comment. Only change was to sub your first comment as one of the labels. I use `ImageSize->{All,300}` to ensure I get it all, otherwise what you state from the docs occurs. But this only works in 2D