# Issue with PieChart3D in Version10. Is it Mac specific?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 or earlier and persisting through 10.0.0 or later**

---

I was testing version 10 to see if the `ImagePadding` bug described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46550/does-the-verticalcallout-algorithm-in-piechart3d-work-correctly) had been fixed and came across a significant issue. The chart (code from linked question) took "forever" to render. `AbsoluteTiming` wrapped around the code kept telling me the timing was ~0.3sec. However the cell bracket remained "active" for ages -- a little after a minute the cell bracket went "inactive" and the chart was rendered in output (I used a stopwatch since the built in timing functions were not capturing the real world delay):

[image]

After experimenting it seems that the problem was arising from `ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileSector3D", "Profile" -> 4]`

```
PieChart3D[{data[[All, 2]]}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileSector3D", "Profile" -> 4], 
 ChartStyle -> 54, ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> All, 
 LabelingFunction -> labeler[data[[All, 1]]], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotRange -> All, 
 SectorOrigin -> {Pi, 0}, SectorSpacing -> 0.2]
```

Further testing showed this problem to occur **only** when both `ChartElementFunction` and `SectorOrigin` where present as options as you can see in the grab below:

[image]

However the examples in the docs for `ChartElementFunction` rendered ok -- but these have `SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}`. So it seems that it is the first position in the `SectorOrigin` list that is the culprit (but only when combined with this `ChartElementFunction` ...I haven't tested other types of `ChartElementFunction` ...yet).

I am running V10.0.0.5098698 on OS X 10.9.4

[image]

It appears others are having no problems on both Mac and Windows. Further monitoring shows the CPU load rising quite dramatically as the front end begins to crap itself:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above was after a restart. The CPU time elapsed (~ 1 minute) is indicative of how long it took for the output to be rendered. When I close V10 and run the same code in V9 output is "instantaneous."

**Also even when the chart is rendered this is not the end of the problem. As soon as the cursor is over the rendered chart the front end freezes again -- CPU usage goes to 100%.**

There is nothing in the underlying box code to indicate what the problem may be. Comparing V9 to V10 I notice that `EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.5]]` in V9 output has been replaced by `EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0],Opacity[0.1]}]` in V10 output, however this replacement occurs in both the working version in 10 (the first example below) and the freezing version. So that doesn't appear to be the issue.

Some test input:

This should work ok:

```
PieChart3D[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileSector3D", "Profile" -> 4], 
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 0}]
```

This next example should take a minute (literally) to render (WARNING. save your work. If you evaluate this >2 times the front end might soil its pants and crash):

```
PieChart3D[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileSector3D", "Profile" -> 4], 
 SectorOrigin -> {Pi, 0}]
```

**Update**

Szabolcs sent me a notebook in which he'd rendered the pie chart. The notebook opened instanteously but as soon as I placed the mouse over the pie chart the front end crapped itself.

Comment: I just tried it in Windows 8.1, it was instantaneous. No problems.

Comment: I have no problems with MMA 10 on OS X 10.8.5 - so maybe it's specific to Mavericks. Can't test on 10.9.4 because I didn't upgrade.

Comment: @Jens interesting. My other Mac is 32 bit so cannot test on that. I have restarted the computer and retested but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm running Mathematica 10 on Mac OS X 10.9.4 (64-bit) and I'm afraid I do not see this problem...

Comment: @RahulNarain really??!!!

Comment: I'm on 10.9.4 too.  The last code block evaluates and renders in a second or so. (By "feeling", I didn't measure precisely.)  Can you try these Mike?  `AbsoluteTiming[expr;]` and `AbsoluteTiming[ToBoxes[expr];]`

Comment: Both versions produce their expected output with V10 on OS X 10.6.8. Both are essentially instantaneous.

Comment: @Szabolcs as i indicated in the question I tried AbsoluteTiming and the output was {0.3, chart} but the output only appeared a minute later!

Comment: @m_goldberg this is getting weird. With V9 it is instantaneous. With V10 the front end sh#*s itself. Strange that no one else is seeing this

Comment: Is it reliably repeatable over multiple restarts of _Mathematica_? Or is it sporadic? I presume you have tried multiple restarts with a clean Front End.

Comment: @m_goldberg yes repeated computer restarts, mathematica restarts, clean front end etc. It is reproducible ...occurs every time as per outline in OP. Am now comparing box code in V9 vs V10 to examine differences.

Comment: I can reliably reproduce your problem on Mac OSX 10.9.4 in V10. Even once it's rendered there's something going on.

Comment: @CameronMurray maybe the problem only effects Australians :)

Comment: Is there an Australian edition of OS X different from the US edition? If so, maybe you're right about this problem only affecting Australians.

Comment: @m_goldberg I was being facetious but maybe a different build was available at the time that the download became available here??

Comment: Though I'm on Windows you get a +1 because I appreciate your frustration.  Apparently M10 has a lot of localized bugs that are hard to reproduce.  I can't believe I'm the only one suffering with [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54763/121), for example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes I couldn't reproduce your issue. I can't think of anything else to try with mine.  :(

Comment: I can think of something else - not using pie charts, aka "The Worst Charts in the World" ;) http://www.businessinsider.com.au/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6

Comment: I'm having a somewhat similar issue with V10 on Win 8.1. After doing any Plot3D/Graphics3D, if I click the output cell, the frontend freezes. It also freezes if I evaluate more than 1 Plot3D/Graphics3D. Apparently, I'm the only one to have this issue???

Comment: @david very strange that this issue seems so random

Comment: If you know whether this has been fixed, would you update the question with that info? Thanks.  (Format: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

Comment: @michaelE2 I do not know. I have used V10 much and not at all for a month. Currently on vacation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed bug by WRI tech support

Comment: Tried the code in Mathematica 10.0 under Linux... same error.  Processor goes to 100% for a long time every time you click on the pie chart.